# Including Sharepoint CSOM in xamarin PCL project

Tags: sharepoint, xamarin.forms, csom

I have included CSOM Online [https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM/] into my PCL project. But the **System.Security.SecureString** not to be found anywhere and makes it unusable in PCL.

As I dug through references I found **SecureString** class in MonoTouch (iOS) and MonoDroid (Android) platforms but not in UWP. I assume the SecureString is the only bottleneck in integrating CSOM with PCL project.

Is there any workaround to include SecureString in UWP projects?

**PS:**
My requirement's like using the service account to authenticate to sharepoint API without user knowledge. Also the SharePoint REST is working fine but I have a lot to do to handle tokens.

CSOM request looks like this

```
var context = new ClientContext("https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxxx");
SecureString password = GetPasswordFromConsoleInput();
String username = "sam@abc.com"
context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName,password);
```

Where the SecureString misses in UWP and PCL